# Remove "function calls" with alphanumeric names and backslashes in a string with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm reading some strings from a file such as this one:

```
s = "Ab [word] 123 \test[abc] hi \abc [] a \command123[there\hello[www]]!"
```

which should be transformed into

```
"Ab [word] 123 abc hi \abc [] a therewww!"
```

Another example is

```
s = "\ human[[[rr] \[A] r \B[] r p\[]q \A[x\B[C]!"
```

which should be transformed into

```
"\ human[[[rr] A r  r pq \A[xC!"
```

How can you generalize this to all similar "functions" with alphanumeric names? By "function" I mean a pattern such as `\name[arg]` where `name` is a (possibly empty) alphanumeric string and `arg` is a (possibly empty) arbitrary string.

Update: After reading kcsquared's comments, I looked through the input files and found stray brackets and backslashes, so I've updated my examples accordingly. The previous regex solution (see below) breaks completely for these special cases:

```
s = re.sub(r'\\command123\[([^}]*)\]', ' \\1', s)
s = re.sub(r'\test\[([^}]*)\]', ' \\1', s) # Fails if this substitution is executed first
s = " ".join(s.split())
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `\t` will be interpreted as tab character. It should be escaped in literal string as `\\test`.

Comment: If there aren't extra `\ ` and `[` characters in your string outside of commands, this isn't too hard. In one pass, you'll want to delete all alphanumeric characters between each `\ ` and the nearest following `[`. Then, in a second pass, delete all `\ `, `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: Thanks, @kcsquared, that's a great idea! Unfortunately, I looked through my input files and found some (rare) stray instances of both `\ ` and `[` characters. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you carefully defined what counts as a "function", and included examples for edge cases. For instance, what should '\A[x\B[C]' become?

Comment: Also, your edge cases should include examples where the 'command' and the 'inner text' may be blank, such as '\\[A]' and '\A[]' and '\\[]'. What should those become?

Comment: Very useful comments, @kcsquared. I updated the post again.

Comment: Thank you for the edits; those are indeed quite helpful. I didn't see any with a pattern like '\A[x\B[C]', which might become 'x\B[C' with non-greedy matching or '\A[xC' with greedy matching. Can you clarify that? Also, the example line is getting pretty long; perhaps it's better to split it into several separate examples for readability.

Comment: Good question, @kcsquared. I think the greedy matching is probably more natural here, but it's definitely an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to push and pop the strings onto it, as if it were a stack.

Scan the string by character and interpret it one by one, don't use regex.